# Populate ScrollView Dynamically with ImageView

Tags: imageview, scrollview, titanium-alloy

I'm new in using Titanium. I tried to load some images into a scrollview. But only one image is loading into the scrollview area. Codes are here

XML

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container">
        <ScrollView showHorizontalScrollIndicator="true" id="Scroll" layout="horizontal">
        </ScrollView>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

JS

```
var scrollView = $.Scroll;
var URLs = ["http://static.flickr.com/41/81743961_588dafe12d_o_d.jpg", "http://static.flickr.com/26/64914466_eed02e2a71_o_d.jpg"];
var Views = [];

for (i =0; i < URLs.length ; i++){

    Views.push(Ti.UI.createImageView({
        image : URLs[i],
        width : Ti.UI.SIZE,
        height : 300,
        top : 0,
        left : 0,
    })
    );
}

Views.forEach(function(view){
    scrollView.add(view);
});

$.index.open();
```

TSS

```
".container": {
    backgroundColor:"white"
},
"#Scroll":{
    width:Ti.UI.SIZE,
    top: 50,
}
```

Screenshot
[image]

I need your help to find out my mistake.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its in your XML file :

```
<Alloy>
<Window class="container">
    <ScrollView showHorizontalScrollIndicator="true" id="Scroll" layout="horizontal">
    </ScrollView>
</Window>
```

you have set the `layout` to `horizontal`, If you will scroll horizontally you will find your second Image there.

Or you can change

`horizontal` to `vertical`

The Image will appear below the first Image.

checkout the [docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-property-layout).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to post update. I found the issue just after posting this question. However, I appreciate your effort for my question.